# How to stop Windows 10 from returning Bluetooth device shortcut in the SendTo folder?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, shortcuts, group-policy, send-to

I'm using windows 10 pro x64 and my problem is that the Bluetooth-device shortcut just by itself keeps showing up inside the SendTo menu, even after I remove that shortcut from the `SendTo` folder (at `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`).

I have tried the solution by making the shortcut invisible using cmd but it is saying file not found. So I tried the second solution that was posted which is this: https://superuser.com/a/1340474/1790574. So I found my local group policy editor and went to User Configuration but after that there is no `Policies` folder so where do I find the `Shortcuts` folder and `Bluetooth File Transfer` in `%SendToDir%` to delete it.

Comment: Under what circumstances does thar shortcut return to this folder? On BT device connection? On restart?

Comment: @BlindSpots I don't see the connection between that and this

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How to stop Windows from adding a Bluetooth shortcut in the SendTo folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1072522/how-to-stop-windows-from-adding-a-bluetooth-shortcut-in-the-sendto-folder)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Windows from adding a Bluetooth shortcut in the SendTo folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/1072522/how-to-stop-windows-from-adding-a-bluetooth-shortcut-in-the-sendto-folder)